# If a java class loaded via UrlClassLoader dynamically, how to scan for it via reflection?

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, classloader

When classes with annotation get loaded via `URLClassLoader`, java reflection mechanism can't see the annotations not in the classpath (They loaded from outside JVM's classpath).

However, e.g. calling `MyLoadedClass.class.getAnnotaions()` shows them.

In particular, I've been trying to scan via reflection annotated classes under a java package but nothing is found.

**How to make such a scan via java reflection work?**

**Update:** as an alternative there's a way to use a bytecode processing library like Javassist or ASM for this purpose. Moreover, it doesn't load classes into JVM but only scans them. I'll try to add a code example here soon.

Comment: Can you provide code samples what exactly does not work? I am not following your questions.

Comment: It's 3 weeks now and still not code example - the question is probably no longer relevant.